# Merging DataFrames returning missing values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two dataframes that I want to merge:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'platform': ['android', 'android','android','android','ios','ios','ios','ios'],
                    'day': [3, 7, 14, 30,3, 7, 14, 30],
                    'value_m' : [1.2, 1.3, 1.7, 1.8,1.6, 2.3, 3.7, 1.8,]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'platform': ['android','ios','ios','android','android','android','ios','ios'],
                    'day': [3, 7, 14, 30, 3, 7, 14, 30],
                    'value_x' : [4, 6, 8, 9,4,6,7,8]})
```

I use the columns platform and day to create a new dataframe that includes the column 'value_x' on my df1. I have tried it with this code:

```
df_pred = df1.merge(df2, left_on=["platform","day"], right_on=["platform","day"], how="left")
df_pred
```

This is what I get:

[image]

I don't understand why it is full of NaNs after using platform and day to pull the data to the new dataframe. Any clue of why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not reproducible, check your data types and update the question with a reproducible sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in real data is because `day` is in one DataFrame string and in another number.

Try in real data convert values to same type:

```
df1['day'] = df1['day'].astype(int)
df2['day'] = df2['day'].astype(int)
```

Your sample data working well.

```
df_pred = df1.merge(df2, on=["platform","day"], how="left")
print (df_pred)
  platform  day  value_m  value_x
0  android    3      1.2      4.0
1  android    3      1.2      4.0
2  android    7      1.3      6.0
3  android   14      1.7      NaN
4  android   30      1.8      9.0
5      ios    3      1.6      NaN
6      ios    7      2.3      6.0
7      ios   14      3.7      8.0
8      ios   14      3.7      7.0
9      ios   30      1.8      8.0
```